# How do I save ModelFrom Data in the Model having ForeignKey of User Model in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, modelform

I have a `Detail` Model that has `ForeignKey` of `User` Model. I also have a `UpdateStudentDetailForm` ModelForm that is based on `Detail` model but also has an extra field that is a dropdown list of users (students), I use this ModelForm use to take input from a current user (teacher). User (teacher) select a user (student) from the dropdown list, fill other fields and submit the form. Now, I want that submitted data to be saved in `Detail` Model of the user (student) that was selected by user (teacher). What should I do in my `views.py` in order to accomplish this?

My `Detail` Model in models.py is below:

```
class Detail(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    skype_session_attendance = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(20)], verbose_name="Skype Session Attendances (of this subject, in numbers)", help_text="Enter the numbers of skype sessions of this subject, the student attended out of 20.")
    internal_course_marks = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(40)], verbose_name="Internal Course Marks (of this subject, in numbers)", help_text="Enter the total internal course marks of this subject, the student obtained out of 40.")
    programming_lab_activity = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(25)], verbose_name="Programming Lab Activities (of this subject, in numbers)", help_text="Enter the total numbers of programming lab activities of this subject, the student participated in, out of 25.")
    mid_term_marks = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(45)], verbose_name="Mid_Term Marks (of this subject, in numbers)", help_text="Enter the total mid-term marks of this subject, the student obtained out of 45.")
    final_term_marks = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(90)], verbose_name="Final_Term Marks (of this subject, in numbers)", help_text="Enter the total final-term marks of this subject, the student obtained out of 90.")

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username}-{self.subject}'
```

My `UpdateStudentDetailsForm` in forms.py is below:

```
STUDENTS_LIST = []
for usr in User.objects.all():
    if not usr.is_staff and not usr.is_superuser:
        STUDENTS_LIST.append(str(usr.first_name + ' ' + usr.last_name + ' - ' + usr.username))

class UpdateStudentDetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    stds = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(choices=STUDENTS_LIST), label='Select a Student')

    class Meta:
        model = Detail

        fields = ['stds', 'subject', 'skype_session_attendance', 'internal_course_marks', 'programming_lab_activity', 'mid_term_marks', 'final_term_marks']
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try :

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

in your Detail model.

Comment: that will mess up every other thing

Comment: because I have developed other views and forms based on `ForeignKey`, not `OneToOneField`